# How to Filter Posts by Custom Fields?

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, loop

I would like to learn the best way to filter custom post types by custom fields.

In the example I am working on, I use custom taxonomies to organize my posts and filter them.

I would like to add the functionality that would allow a user to filter posts by price and bedrooms in the ascending and descending order.

[image]

Price and Bedrooms are custom fields.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What had you tried and how far you got? What specific issues you hit trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not provided any code, below code snippet assumes a 'property' as post type and price as meta field. I think the code will provide you some direction and you can take it from there. Feel free to make changes as needed:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'property',
              'meta_key' => 'price',
              'orderby' => 'meta_value',
              'order' => 'ASC',
              'meta_query' => array(array('key' => 'price','compare' => '=',))
              );
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: `LIKE` comparison is slow and is typically for string comparison. Using `=` will be much faster.